# How do I get containsignorecase for java?

Tags: android

I am trying to use contains for strings coinciding with the search symbols. However, seems like contains does not have an ignore case unlike equals. Is there any way to go around ?

The following line of code is where I am using the same (I have heard of pattern, but how do I use the same in my case? )

```
searchSymbol.contains(mSearchView.getText().toString()
```

Thanks!
Justin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just convert them both to lower case and use `contains()` as normal:

```
searchSymbol.toLowerCase().contains(mSearchView.getText().toString().toLowerCase())
```

---

You could write your own function to do this if you want to keep it clean:

```
public static boolean containsIgnoreCase(String haystack, String needle){
    return haystack.toLowerCase().contains(needle.toLowerCase());
}
```

---

You could use the function from `StringUtils`:

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase("testString", "stSt");
```

---

In any case, you're going to want to watch out for unicode characters. They don't play by the normal rules of "case" in most circumstances.

Comment: works great thanks, but how do I create it such that if(something) holds along with this: if(something && something with space) , like a string say "google apple" how do i recognize such a string with a space in the if loop?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but it sounds like a candidate for a separate question. You might want to give a few examples of what you're trying to do there.

Comment: no worries, i added it as a different question, here's the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728426/how-do-you-concatenate-two-values-with-a-space-in-between