# How do you concatenate two values with a space in between?

Tags: android

I am trying to concatenate two strings with a space in between as follows:

```
if(searchSymbol.toLowerCase().contains(mSearchView.getText().toString().toLowerCase()) + "HERE COMES THE SPACE" +searchSymbol.toLowerCase().contains(mSearchView.getText().toString().toLowerCase())  )
```

{}

I am just not sure how to define the same? should I use  (1st string&&+""&&""+ 2nd string). Any help appreciated.

Thanks!
Justin

Comment: you mean like "texttexttext"+" "+"moretext";?

Comment: yes, pretty much like recognizing 2 typed names "google apple"

Comment: I don't get your issue. You already have the working solution, don't you?

Comment: yeah, seems like you have it to me, just replace `HERE COMES THE SPACE` with `" "`

Comment: will it recognize the "" as a space in between?

Comment: if((searchSymbol.contains(mSearchView.getText().toString()))&&""&&(searchSymbol.contains(mSearchView.getText().toString()))){} is showing an error for the && or +, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why exactly do you have a if statement in your code... Are you concatenating a string then checking its value? In that case...

if((str1 + " " + str2).equals(str3)){}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if statement is a little confusing to read

I would change it to

```
String text = string1 + " " + string2;

if(text.equals("string3")){

}
```

`""` is not a space but `" "` is a space

Comment: Thanks, but on the lines of this, I was wondering how do I delegate the search symbol defined in a class say class A to be used (remembered and passed over) to class B , such that I can use the same search symbol in another class.say for example : I am defining  protected EditList searchSymbol; if(searchsymbol....) { FragmentA}, and I want to get this search symbol in anopther class such that the same value passed for searchSymbol can be added in class b as NEW_TEXT="http://www.google.com/q="+searchSymbol+"%20revenue...", how do I do the same?

Answer (score 0):

If its used a lot in your class, just declare a `final String SPACE = " ";`
and use it in the code when required.

```
private final String SPACE = " ";
String spaceString = "String1" + SPACE + "String2";
```

Comment: Yep, bad downvote. +1 from me to help restore the natural balance of the Androidverse.

Comment: Actually even though I didn't downvote this, I can understand why it was. It's a bit like defining `private final String A = "A";` where is the sense in that? Sorry, no offense but I just don't get it. Then again I'm not sure what the OP of this question is trying to do either.